# King's Cup game

Tags: javascript, html, css, game, playing-cards

I just wrote a small card game in JavaScript, CSS and HTML. This is kind of my first project that I have cared about front-end. So I got things to work, but I am sure that this is not the smartest way to do it.

If someone could give me some guidelines on how this would have been done in a more professional way I would be very thankful.

```
window.turn_counter = 0;
window.kings = 0;
window.game = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#help').hide();
    $('#turn').hide();
    $('#card').hide();
    $('#count').hide();
    $('#rule_text').hide();
    $('#game_buttons').hide();
    $('#set_up').hide();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    //Add this to all the inputs
  if (e.keyCode == '32' || e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (game == true){
        pull_card();
    }
  }
});
});

function start(){
    $('#welcome_screen').hide();
    $('#set_up').show();
    $('#set_up').append('<input type="text" ' +
                'class="input_field center" id="num" ' +
                'value="Number of players">' +
                '<img alt="setup button" ' + 
                'class="button center" ' +
                'onclick="set_players()" ' +
                'src="static/button_proceed.png">');
}

function hide_help(){
    $('#help').hide();
    $('#game_components').show();
}

function show_help(){
    $('#game_components').hide();
    $('#help').show();
}

function set_players(){
        var number = document.getElementById('num').value;
        number = parseInt(number);
        //Need do something if string is entered.
        window.number_of_players = number;
        $('#set_up').empty();

    for(i = 0; i < window.number_of_players; i++){
        var player_number = i + 1;
        $('#set_up').append('<input class="input_field center"' + 
                    ' value="Player #' + 
                    player_number + '" type="text" id="' + 
                    i + '" >');
    }
    $('.set_up').append('<img alt="proceed button" id="proceed_button" ' +
                'class="center button" src="static/button_proceed.png"' + 
                ' onclick=register_players()>');
 }

function register_players(){
    players = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < window.number_of_players; i++){
        players[i] = document.getElementById(i).value;
    }
    window.players = players;
    set_up_rules();
}

function set_up_rules(){
    $('.set_up').empty();
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        if (i == 0){
            name = 'Ace';
        }
        else if (i == 10){
            name = 'Jack';
        }
        else if (i == 11){
            name = 'Queen';
        }

    else{
        name = 'card ' + (i + 1);
    }
    $('.set_up').append('<input value="Rule for ' + 
                name + '" class="input_field center" id="other' + 
                i + '" type="text">');
}   
$('.set_up').append('<br><img alt="setup button" class="button center"' + 
            ' src="static/button_startgame.png" ' + 
            'onclick="set_rules()">');
}

function set_rules(){
    rule_set = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        card_rule = document.getElementById('other' + i).value;
        rule_set[i] = card_rule;
    }
    rule_set[12] = 'KINGS CUP!!'
    window.rule_set = rule_set; 
    start_game();
}

function start_game(){
    new_deck();
    pull_card();
    $('#help_button').hide();
    $('#set_up').hide();
    $('#turn').show();
    $('#card').show();
    $('#game_buttons').show();
    game = true;
}

function pull_card(){
    item = Math.random() * deck.length;
    card = window.deck.splice(item,1);
    display_card(card);
}

function display_card(card){
    //weird flash, need to empty content for each card
    game_buttons = '<img class="center button" alt="next card button" ' +
            'src="static/button_nextcard.png" ' +
            'onclick="pull_card()" >' +
            '<img class="center button" alt="remind me of rule button" ' + 
            'src="static/button_remindme.png" ' + 
            'onclick="display_rule()" >';

if(card < 1){
    alert("Deck is empty. The game will reload");
    window.location.reload();
    }

current_turn = get_current_turn()
turn = get_next_turn()    

//need to be called to check if it is the last king
get_rule(card, current_turn)

//needs to be done to prevent weird flash
$('#game_buttons').empty();
$('#card').empty();
$('#card').append('<img class="center" alt="' + card + '"src=/static/cards/' + 
            card + '.png >');
$('#game_buttons').append(game_buttons);
$('#turn').empty();

if (current_turn != undefined){
    $('#turn').append('<h2 class="center" >Current player: ' + 
                current_turn + '</h2>');
}

if (turn != undefined){
    $('#turn').append('<h2 class="center">Next player: ' + 
    turn + '</h2>'); 
}

}

function get_next_turn(){
    //add test on get number
    if (window.turn_counter == (window.players.length - 1)){
        window.turn_counter = -1;
    }
    window.turn_counter += 1;
    player = window.players[window.turn_counter];
    return player;     
}

function get_current_turn(){
    return window.players[window.turn_counter];
}

function get_rule(card, player){
    num = String(card);
    num = num.substring(1);
    if (num == 13){
        window.kings +=1;
        if (window.kings == 4){
            if (player == undefined){
                alert('LAST KING! Congratulations!')
            }
        else{
            alert('LAST KING! Congratulations ' + player + '!')
        }
    }
}
return window.rule_set[num - 1];
}

function display_rule(){
    rule = get_rule(card, get_current_turn());
    alert(rule);
}

function new_deck(){
var deck = new Array(
            'd1',
            'd2',
            'd3',
            'd4',
            'd5',
            'd6',
            'd7',
            'd8',
            'd9',
            'd10',
            'd11',
            'd12',
            'd13',
            'h1',
            'h2',
            'h3',
            'h4',
            'h5',
            'h6',
            'h7',
            'h8',
            'h9',
            'h10',
            'h11',
            'h12',
            'h13',
            'c1',
            'c2',
            'c3',
            'c4',
            'c5',
            'c6',
            'c7',
            'c8',
            'c9',
            'c10',
            'c11',
            'c12',
            'c13',
            's1',
            's2',
            's3',
            's4',
            's5',
            's6',
            's7',
            's8',
            's9',
            's10',
            's11',
            's12',
            's13'
            );
    window.deck = deck;
}
```

I won't post the HTML and CSS for now, but you can find the game [here](http://kingscuponline.appspot.com/).

Comment: My eyes. The code is far too procedural. Modularize it.

Comment: You might also have a look at CoffeeScript. It helps you write nicer JS.

Answer (score 3):

For starters don't store any of your variables in the global scope (I.E. window.xxx).  Your whole came can be enclosed using the module pattern.  To use the module pattern you'll do something like this:

```
//note that the var game isn't even required if you are only attaching events in here, the var is only needed if there are methods that your module needs to return properties or functions for other parts of your page to use them. 
var game = (function(window, document, undefined){
    //so here you are caching your display elements and putting them in a Object
    var displayElements = {
        help : $('#help'),
        turn : $('#turn'),
        card : $('#card'),
        welcomeScreen :  $('#welcome_screen'),
        setUp : $('#set_up'),
        ....
    },
    numberOfPlayers = 0;
    //anyother stuff you have in your window here

     function start(){
         displayElements.welcomeScreen.hide();
         displayElements.welcomeScreen.hide();
         $('#set_up').append('<input type="text" ' +
                'class="input_field center" id="num" ' +
                'value="Number of players">' +
                '<img alt="setup button" ' + 
                'class="button center" ' +
                'onclick="set_players()" ' +
                'src="static/button_proceed.png">');
     }

     function hide_help(){
         displayElements.help.hide();
         displayElements.gameComponents.show();
     }

     //put your other functions here
}(window, window.document);
```

Another thing I'd do is create some generic functions for things like hiding elements.  This is a typical pattern called a forEach:

```
 function hideElems(elems){
     for(var i = 0; i < elemen.len; i++){
          var elem = elems[i];
          function hide(){
              elem.hide();  //here you won't need jquery since you alredy have jquery objects that you created in the elements object
          }
     }
 }
```

Now instead of having:

```
$('#help').hide();
$('#turn').hide();
$('#card').hide();
$('#count').hide();
$('#rule_text').hide();
$('#game_buttons').hide();
$('#set_up').hide();
```

you'd have:

```
  hideElems([displayElements.help,displayelements.turn...]);
```

The nice thing about this is that you can call it with any number of elements at a time.  There's a lot more I can add but I have to get back to work.  I'll see if I can come back tomorrow and add some more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. And it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Pecock You're welcome.  I'm curious to what I'd else you'd like me to add to my answer to make it "upvote" worthy.

Comment: Sorry, This is perfect, but I can't vote up before I have gained 15 reputaion. And this is my first question, I will do it once I've reached the limit.

Comment: @Pecock No, worries.  I just was wondering if I could do anything to make my answer better in your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great start. To Raynos' point you could modularize this into more manageable chunks. Here are a is jQuery Pattern article to help you get started: [Essential jQuery Plugin Patterns by Addy Osmani](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that article. I think that is something I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things would make this cleaner.

Like the others said ... modularize/plugin-ize it etc. in the proccess don't have

```
window.GlobalVariableName = someVal;
```

instead make an object:

```
window.MyCardGame = {
    GlobalVariableName: somVal,

    GlobalFunction: function (){ ... }
};
```

Or a closure

```
(function(){
    var Global = val; // Global variable to anything in this closure only.
})();
```

patterns like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    if (i == 0){
        name = 'Ace';
    }
    else if (i == 10){
        name = 'Jack';
    }
    else if (i == 11){
        name = 'Queen';
    }

    else{
        name = 'card ' + (i + 1);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

can be expressed with a switch which is 
cleaner/easier to read (IMHO):

```
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
            name = 'Ace';
            break;
        case 10:
            name = 'Jack';
            break;
        case 11:
            name = 'Queen';
            break;
        default:
            name = 'card ' + (i + 1);
            break;
    }
    // etc.
}
```

*ps: Where is the king?*

When you do

```
$("#elementID").someFN();
$("#elementID").otherFN();
```

It has to get the same element twice. jQuery has the ability to chain:

```
$("#elementID").someFN().otherFN();
// OR
$("#elementID")
    .someFN()
    .otherFN();
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot of sense. But the closure, that is just a function that wraps around a set of functions to isolate things?
And the King can't be changed, so I have not included it in that method/array

Comment: @Pecock Long live the King! ... The closure is just to isolate your variables/namespace so it doesn't screw up other code.  Us developers can be an unoriginal bunch in naming things at times and two developers might use the same name for two different pieces of code. Closures minimise this sort of conflict.  I'm not the best teacher of this so I would suggest a quick google search for them.

Comment: @JamesKhoury, your example isn't really a closure, thats an Instantly Invoked Function Expression AKA IIFE, which is part of the JavaScript module pattern.

Comment: @bittersweetryan No but a self invoking function creates a closure. As I said I'm not the best teacher on that subject but: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/ and http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml and http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ and http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html seem to be good places to start learning.